# Control all controls from Login form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have Login form and after that Main form with a lot of more mini forms. I am planning to put in my application some type of mini roles. My idea is to take the logged-in user at logging, see his role and do what needs to be done ( disable some controls for example ).

The problem is that I do not know how to control the controls on other forms from the initial form.

Any advice?

Comment: Better: don't access controls on other forms from the login form.  Instead, use a property of the login form to tell other forms what role the user has, so each form can manage itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit controls in main form you can use foreach loop:

First declare second form:

```
SecondForm second = new SecondForm();
```

Then foreach all controls:

```
foreach(Control c in second.Controls)
{
    c.Text = "hello world!";
}
```

And you can use `.GetType()` to get type of control:

```
foreach(Control c in second.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        c.Text = "hello world!";
}
```

If you want to disable some controls you can do it by name:

```
foreach(Control c in second.Controls)
{
    if (c.Name == "button1")
        c.Enabled = false;
}
```

Or you can disable it by type with `.GetType()`:

```
foreach(Control c in second.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        c.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))`, use `if (c is Button)`.  Cleaner and actually works if there is inheritance going on.